# Can't multiply two matrices, where hight and width are defined by template

Tags: c++, class, templates, operators

I wrote Class Matrix, parameters of which I define by template. So when I tried to declare operator* between two matrices, I found out? that Cpp counts matrices with different parameters as different classes (For example 7x3 and 3x5). How can I avoid this?

Here is my class

```
template <size_t N, size_t M, typename T = int64_t>
class Matrix {
 public:
  Matrix();
  Matrix(std::vector<std::vector<T>> const input);
  Matrix(const T elem);

  Matrix operator+(const Matrix& other) const;
  Matrix& operator+=(const Matrix& other);
  Matrix operator-(const Matrix& other) const;
  Matrix& operator-=(const Matrix& other);
  Matrix operator*(const T& other) const;
  Matrix& operator*=(const T& other);

  Matrix operator*(const Matrix& other) const;
  Matrix& operator*=(const Matrix& other);

  Matrix Transposed();
  T Trace();

  T& operator()(const size_t i, const size_t j) const;

  bool operator==(const Matrix& other) const;

 private:
};
```

Cppref did not helped :(

Comment: You cannot declare operator* as a regular member of your class because then both matrices have to be the same size. But there is nothing to stop you declaring it outside of your class, then you can have as many template parameters as you think are necessary.

Comment: What you want to avoid? Matrix<M,N,T> can be multiplied with Matrix<N,P,T> and result will be Matrix<M,P,T> so your inline operator* needs one additional template argument P.

Comment: Ohh, It is the way! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template arguments are part of the type; otherwise they couldn't be considered in type resolution and SFINAE. Thus, there are two choices:

- either make `N, M` runtime arguments of e.g. `Matrix` (or can even be deduced from current `input`), thereby making it non-template, or
- you live with the fact that the concrete class depends on `N, M` and, optionally, you might have a base class where this part of the type is erased; or, if you don't need a common base type, you might have the operator as a template and then you might have a different Matrix on the rhs.

The latter can be like this:

```
typename<T = int64_t>
class Matrix {
  Matrix();
  Matrix(std::vector<std::vector<T>> const input);
  Matrix(const T elem);

  // other operators, functions

  virtual Matrix operator*(const Matrix& other) const;
};

template <size_t N, size_t M, typename T = int64_t>
class FixedSizeMatrix : Matrix<T> {
  // as now, possibly with override when appropriate
  Matrix<N, M1> operator*(const Matrix& other) const override /* final? */;
};
```

However, this will be slower, due to virtual resolution. If you don't need a common base:

```
template <size_t N, size_t M, typename T = int64_t>
class Matrix {
 public:
  // as before

  template<size_t N1, size_t M1, typename T2 = int64_t>
  Matrix operator*(const Matrix<N1, M1, T2>& other) const;
};


Main question to ask yourself is, why you want `N, M` to be compile-time arguments.
```

Comment: This could be the solution, but, unfortunately, I cant make N, M runtime arguments for some reasons. So Is there no way to declare multiplication with such conditions?

Comment: @Kruzenger Read the second part of the answer.

Comment: The templated `Matrix::operator*` should probably return a `Matrix<N, M1>` instead of a `Matrix`